# Calculations on dynamic date variable

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

Im using Oracle SQL platform and Im using a variable @Quarter to prompt for a Quarter and related data that I want to see. This variable is based on a column that has a format "YYYY QQ" (for example "2018 Q2").

Now Its really easy to pass that variable but how can I add a time to this variable to get a next or previous quarter?

I tried: `TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_QUARTER, -1, @QUARTER')`

and the sql issued looked like:

```
(TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_QUARTER, -1, '2017 Q 4')
```

unfortunately my variable doesnt have appropriate format, its just "2017 Q 4" so not a timestamp...

I also tried: `TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_QUARTER, -1, CAST('@QUARTER' AS DATE))`

and the sql issued looked:

```
(TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_QUARTER, -1, CAST('2017 Q 4' AS DATE)))
```

like it didnt even recognize the function CAST inside...

Is there anything I can do to make a calculations on that variable?

Many Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Those issues statement aren't Oracle SQL, so is OBIEE interpeting them further, or are your getting ORA- errors? It's usually helpful to include whatever errors you do get, whether they're from Oracle or OBIEE or somewhere else.

Comment: Include whatever you do see for each attempt in your question (as formatted text). I'm unclear if you're looking for an Oracle SQL solution or something specific to OBIEE, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: There is no ORA errors, for each attempt in my question Im getting: Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43113. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 27002. [nQSError: 27002] Near <Q>: Syntax error (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 26012. [nQSError: 26012] . (HY000)

Comment: And its because it doesnt recognize the format "2018 Q2" in my timestampadd statement. And yes, its Oracle Sales Analytics.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include further information or clarifications. Comment section is for comments, which are consider transitory. Also, code and sample data are hard to read without proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut up your input with substr and get it into a date format within the Quarter's range.  Then you'll just need to add quarters (shown as quarters * 3 months: `-1 * 3` and `1 * 3` in my example) to get those before/after.

```
with x as (select '2017 Q4' as input from dual)
select input,
    to_date(substr(input,1,4) || '-' || substr(input,7,1) * 3, 'yyyy-mm') as in_date_format,
    to_char(add_months(to_date(substr(input,1,4) || '-' || substr(input,7,1) * 3, 'yyyy-mm'), -1 * 3), 'yyyy "Q"q') as last_quarter,
    to_char(add_months(to_date(substr(input,1,4) || '-' || substr(input,7,1) * 3, 'yyyy-mm'), 1 * 3), 'yyyy "Q"q') as next_quarter
from x;
```

Without seeing your code, this is the best I could do to represent what I am talking about...